# How to remove non-project files from refactorings in Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, refactoring, rename, projects-and-solutions

For some reason when I try to do a rename refactor, idea picks up code that is not even remotely close to my project. Furthermore, this code is read-only and I can't edit it! And Non-Project Access dialog is almost mockingly "ultimate" in its options: I can only choose whether I want to edit the non-project files this time or I want to do this ALWAYS. No option to skip these files altogether.

I tried to add these folders as a content root and exclude them - it didn't help. And I can't remove them, since they actually don't show up as files in the refactor preview (they are not referenced anywhere in the project view either), only {m} functions/method do with no option to remove them.

So the refactor rightfully fails because it can't edit RO files. So how would I solve this?

Comment: What code construct are you renaming, is it Python? What code is erroneously suggested for refactoring: where is it located, is it the library file?

Comment: Yes. It's python. I have to copies of the project. One in stored in location A and is read-only. The other is one I'm currently editing and it's stored in location B (not anywhere close to A). When I try to run a renaming refactor pycharm somehow also picks up files from RO version of the project (I've opened it once in IDE before but there are no files/references in the current project).

Comment: @Andrey I think I've managed to solve my problem though the solution was a bit weird. I had to change my python interpreter. Before, I had selected external python from some venv. And Idea for some reason picked up the project files that were related to that venv.
Not sure if it's a bug, either way seems like a big usability anti-feature (inability to skip refactor for selected items).

Comment: The solution for me was to create a new, clean virtualenv for the project. This behavior still seems buggy in my case, because I was modifying a fork of the project that was included in the system packages. The fork itself was not included in system packages, though.